# Ninject bind mulitple implementations to an interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm looking at this tutorial, but not quite understanding how to create a factory that can provide me separate implementations of an interface.

http://stefanoricciardi.com/2011/01/21/ninject-mini-tutorial-part-1/

```
public class IJob {
  ...
}

public class JobImpl1 : IJob {
  ...
}

public class JobImpl2 : IJob {
  ...
}

using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel()) {
    kernel.Bind<IJob>().To<JobImpl2>(); 
    var job = kernel.Get<IJob>();
}
```

My goal is to make a factory class that wraps this Ninject Kernel so I can provide different implementations of my IJob interface depending on whether I'm in a unit test environment vs a live environment.  However, I also want to keep the Ninject hidden inside the factory wrapper so that the rest of the code will not depend on Ninject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate extension [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory) that allows you to generate *Abstract Factory* implementation on fly based on *interface*

### Kernel configuration

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

// wire concrete implementation to abstraction/interface
kernel.Bind<IJob>().To<JobImpl1>()
    .NamedLikeFactoryMethod<IJob, IJobFactory>(f => f.GetJob());

// configure IJobFactory to be Abstract Factory
// that will include kernel and act according to kernel configuration    
kernel.Bind<IJobFactory>().ToFactory();
```

### Resolve *Abstract Factory* at runtime using kernel

```
// get an instance of Abstract Factory
var abstractFactory = kernel.Get<IJobFactory>();

// resolve dependency using Abstract Factory
var job = abstractFactory.GetJob()
```

### Abstract Factory interface

```
public interface IJobFactory
{
    IJobFactory GetJob();
}
```

Comment: This feels like it's on the right track, but what I need is to be able to have multiple implementations of the same interface in the same environment.  An example would be where I need multiple implementations of an IVehicle interface (truck, car, motorcycle, etc.)

Comment: Add new methods signatures to _Abstract Factory_ and use _NamedLikeFactoryMethod_ to configure mapping